# How can I do large file delivery system (YouSendIt) on my own server?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, email, mysql, ftp

I'm wondering if there is a way that I can replicate the large file delivery system on my own server like the way YouSendIt works.  I upload a file on a page, server recognizes it and sends an email to the specified recipient.

When they download it, the file is deleted.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

hm guess you would have to look at the http response code the client sends to the server after the file transfer stops. If it is 2XX, you can assume that the client got the file and mark it as delivered.

Answer (score 0):

[Quixly](http://quixly.com/) functions as a hosted service, but has an option that allows for the actual file storage to be on your own server(scroll to bottom). It's pretty inexpensive, even if you let it host the files for you. Transfers can be set to expire based on time, or number of downloads. Note I don't see it specifically mentioned that expired files are *deleted*(you'll have to check on that yourself), but I'm operating on the assumption the one-time-only aspect is more important than the cleanup to you.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for Quixly, I will look into it.